# Bridged VLAN and VAC can't connect to the internet on DD-WRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, vlan

I just recieved my new Netgear Nighthawk AC router, and I installed the latest DD-WRT from myopenrouter.com (build 23720).  I am trying to create a VLAN bridged with a Virtual Access Point (VAC) so that all of my wired and wireless devices will be on their own network at 192.168.10.1.  I want it to have DHCP and to be able to connect to the internet.  So far I am able to bridge the connections and assign ip addresses, but no internet access.

Here is my current configuration.
[image: VLANS page]

[image: Networking page 1]

[image: Networking page 2]

[image: Routing tables]

In the future I would like to be able to configure this with custom NAT forwarding rules, etc, but for now I need to figure out internet.  I've tried a lot of different combinations, but so far none of them work, and the one presented is the most progress I have made.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: might be usefull [How to setup multiple BSSIDs using DD-WRT](http://www.pennock.nl/dd-wrt/Multiple_BSSIDs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Run as administrator then commands save to firewall

```
if [ "`nvram get wan_proto`" = "pppoe" ]; then
  wanif="`nvram get pppoe_ifname`"
else
  wanif="`nvram get wan_ifname`"
fi

# Make sure br1 has access to the internet:
iptables -I INPUT -i br1 -m state --state NEW -j logaccept
iptables -I FORWARD -i br1 -o $wanif -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```